# I can't load the devexpress library

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

In my Asp.Net Core MVC5 application, I keep getting jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).dxDataGrid is not a function TypeError: $(...).dxDataGrid is not a function, even though I complete all libraries
I tried all the simple examples I found on the internet. None worked, it loads successfully in jquery. Do I have to do something in my project's settings?

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/23.1.3/css/dx.common.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/23.1.3/css/dx.light.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/23.1.3/js/dx.all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
   
</head>

<body>

    <div class="dx-viewport demo-container">
        <div id="gridContainer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(() => {
        $('#gridContainer').dxDataGrid({
            dataSource: customers,
            keyExpr: 'ID',
            columns: ['CompanyName', 'City', 'State', 'Phone', 'Fax'],
            showBorders: true,
        });
    });


    const customers = [{
        ID: 1,
        CompanyName: 'Super Mart of the West',
        Address: '702 SW 8th Street',
        City: 'Bentonville',
        State: 'Arkansas',
        Zipcode: 72716,
        Phone: '(800) 555-2797',
        Fax: '(800) 555-2171',
        Website: 'http://www.nowebsitesupermart.com',
    }, {
        ID: 2,
        CompanyName: 'Electronics Depot',
        Address: '2455 Paces Ferry Road NW',
        City: 'Atlanta',
        State: 'Georgia',
        Zipcode: 30339,
        Phone: '(800) 595-3232',
        Fax: '(800) 595-3231',
        Website: 'http://www.nowebsitedepot.com',
    }, {
        ID: 3,
        CompanyName: 'K&S Music',
        Address: '1000 Nicllet Mall',
        City: 'Minneapolis',
        State: 'Minnesota',
        Zipcode: 55403,
        Phone: '(612) 304-6073',
        Fax: '(612) 304-6074',
        Website: 'http://www.nowebsitemusic.com',
    }];

</script>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the jQuery library script **BEFORE** the DevExtreme one (i.e., exchange them in your snippet):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/23.1.3/js/dx.all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```